# Ionic slider not showing content initially

Tags: angularjs, templates, slider, ionic-framework, angular-ui

When i load a template on click of button using $state.go() slider embedded in template not displaying its content.

When i rotated my device then it start showing the slides.
Please sugggest what i am missing in this code snippet of template.

```
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="" show-pager="true">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="placementStep in placementSteps">
          <div class="list card"> 

              <div class="item-divider">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <h1 class="title">{{placementStep.stepName}}</h1>  
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                  <button class="button icon ion-chevron-right button-positive button-small right"  ng-if="$index!=placementSteps.length-1&& placementStep.studentsForStep.length!=0" ng-click="moveStudents(placementStep,placementSteps,0)"></button>

                    <button class="button icon ion-chevron-left button-positive button-small  right"  ng-if="$index!=0 && placementStep.studentsForStep.length!=0" ng-click="moveStudents(placementStep,placementSteps,1)"></button> 

                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <ion-list show-reorder="data.showReorder" can-swipe="false" ng-class="has-header">

                <ion-item ng-repeat="student in placementStep.studentsForStep">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="left checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="student.checked==true" ng-model="student.checked">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col vertical-center">
                   {{student.first_name}} 
                  </div>

                </div> 

            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>  
         </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used delegate handle to update the slide box after loading data. It worked.

```js
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('placementStepSlideBox').update();
```

Where "placmentStepSlideBox" is the delegate handle name.

Comment: Can you please tell what is delegate handle name and where should i mention it?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?In mobile the slider is not working for first time.If i give auto rotate enabled in mobile and rotate to fullscreen then slider displays.

Answer (score 1):

Call This function,

```
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
```

Immediately after loading the image files or directly within the controller definition for that view.

notice the absence of of the getbyhandle();